# How to exclude a process from lsof

Tags: lsof

On my system (debian wheezy), lsof (make by checkrestart) take a very long time, 15 minutes.
After search, i suppose that is occur because we have a lot off child in a process (3000).

Can i exclude a process in lsof ?

Thanks,

Comment: i have solve my issue with a `lsof -u ^user`.
like this, i can exclude openfile for a particular user that own process.

Comment: You can also use negation with a process, example:

Comment: `sudo lsof -p ^1234` will display all PIDs except those starting with 1234